# Java Selenium 3.5.3 Wait for css-class to change

Tags: java, selenium

is there any way to look for a CSS-classchange of an element with Selenium?

The class marks the element, which is currently selected in the Browser.

```
    <span class="tabs2_tab guide_tab"> [...] </span>
```

On click the site refreshes and changes the class to...

```
<span class="tabs2_tab guide_tab is-required"> [...] </span>
```

I already tried waiting for the browser to finish loading, but it won't really work, because I can't get the driver to wait for *this* CSS-Class change. Apparently this is the only change I can refer to, in case of defining the state of the site. It seems like the frame refreshes, but the elements stay the exact same, excluding *this* class.

I am currently working with a site, which is actually pretty bad to work with, because of missing ID's and similiar stuff. Needlessly to say, that this is neither my site, nor can I edit the code.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How about waiting for this css element `span.tabs2_tab.guide_tab.is-required`? It will only come when the css has actually changed

Comment: There are multiple elements like that, sadly.

Comment: so how would you reach this element to check for the CSS change?

Comment: In this <span> there are other elements, which caption i address with the XPath. Basically i throw them all in a list, then filter for the caption of the element within the <span>

Comment: So i think this is possible to do, but i need part of the HTML which has captions form 2-3 tabs on the page so I can comment better and provide you a solution

Answer (score 0):

In C# I use this to check if `WebElement` attribute has changed and as far as I know for Java the same pattern can be used. This method only looks if `value` of attribute specified by `name` was changed.

Let's assume you have your `driver` instance somewhere as good as `desiredTimeout`. So in C# you have:

```
public void WaitForAttributeToChange(IWebElement element, string name, string previousValue)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, desiredTimeout);
        wait.Until((d) =>
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute(name) != previousValue)
            {
                return element;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

And after that you can call it like:

```
WaitForAttributeToChange(yourElement, "class", "previous_class_here");
```

This worked with size changes so I suppose if you translate this into Java it may do the trick. As far as i know, Java do have lambda expressions, so you should be fine.